# How do I build a Unity project using the Firebase SDK for tvOS?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, tvos

Using macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.2, Xcode 14.2, Unity 2021.3.16f1, Cocoapods 1.11.3, and Firebase SDK for Unity 10.3.

I am able to build our project for macOS and iOS from Unity without any problems. However, once I re-target tvOS (device, not simulator), the project is raising hundreds of build errors that look like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_Firebase_App_CSharp_AppEnableLogCallback", referenced from:
      _AppUtil_AppEnableLogCallback_m9FE8159D116019E4E918F4B7CEC39687DD64B2EA in Firebase.App.o
      _AppUtilPINVOKE_AppEnableLogCallback_m5BB69B725FD3DF1FE26C20DE516F14E02E82BDB3 in Firebase.App.o
  "_Firebase_App_CSharp_AppGetLogLevel", referenced from:
      _AppUtilPINVOKE_AppGetLogLevel_m1FA70677F6D87B20549848E73B88B7A9CE5E6A33 in Firebase.App.o
      _AppUtil_AppGetLogLevel_m613922E721681B614FB13D09809624C3EA70497E in Firebase.App.o
  "_Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_ApiKey_get", referenced from:
      _AppOptionsInternal_get_ApiKey_m4FEA968CCE295C61306024A53B87EB462C793FDD in Firebase.App.o
      _AppUtilPINVOKE_AppOptionsInternal_ApiKey_get_mE56BE832D66D5DF3061815D009AE7F2AEB6C59F8 in Firebase.App.o
  "_Firebase_App_CSharp_AppOptionsInternal_ApiKey_set", referenced from:
      _AppOptionsInternal_set_ApiKey_mCF8BDC7C43BB152665C3F48096C5B239291B75DD in Firebase.App.o
      _AppUtilPINVOKE_AppOptionsInternal_ApiKey_set_m47AA8DEF19EB00D363BD710D4AB35D0F71D3810C in Firebase.App.o
```

I looked online, but didn't see anyone else having this problem. It's like there's a file missing from the build, but my searches within the project haven't been turning up anything.

How do I get this to build? Or does the Firebase SDK just not support tvOS?

I was expecting this to build like it does on iOS and macOS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is a build problem, not a code problem.